# How to manage single session on two different php scripts?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have installed two different PHP scripts on my server. One on root and another on different sub-directory. However, I want the root phpscript's users session to be continued on another sub-directory script. I need this session to enable chat even on another directory script.

The sub directory is [os-class](http://osclass.org). 
I made a different PHP file on sub-directory to track session variables.

```
Array ( [user_email] => xxxx@example.com
        [users_id] => 275
        [first_name] => Sammy
        [last_name] => Durha
        [username] => 275
        [mobile] => XXXXXXXXX
        [chat_sms_sent] => message sent to off line friends. )
```

However on one of the script page the half session gets lost.

```
Array ( [messages] => Array ( )
        [keepForm] => Array ( )
        [form] => Array ( )
        [chat_sms_sent] => message sent to off line friends. )
```

Can anyone please sort out the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are not tied to a directory. If you call `session_start()` at the top of both scripts, the `$_SESSION` variable should have the same content in both.

Comment: but why session [user_email] => xxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com [users_id] => 275 [first_name] => Sammy [last_name] => Durha [username] => 275 [mobile] are lost when session_start is called on new script?

Answer (score 0):

Session is independent of directories and files. It can be used universally. But remember that sessions are less secure.

You may follow a simple tutorial [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php/).